# Validate routing number

Tags: java, android

How to validate bank routing number in java ?
can any one help me out.
for example

```
void boolean validate(String str){

  // some code
  return true;     //if valid otherwise return false
}
```

Comment: Can you describe in words what a valid number looks like? Give us some examples too, please.

Comment: 2min Google Search: check this out `http://www.brainjar.com/js/validation/` or this `http://geek.michaelgrace.org/2013/12/validating-bank-routing-numbers-in-javascript/` or this `http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=6582`

Comment: @nem Any reason you made all those links unclickable?

Comment: @Duncan by accident, i wanted to highlight them. When I realized it was too late to edit :)

Comment: Did you know that the structure of a valid routing number varies by country?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. Bank Routing Number is validate by using this simple method.

```
public boolean validateRoutingNumber(String s) {

    int checksum=0, len=0, sum=0, mod = 0;
    len = s.length();

    if(len != 9){
        return false;
    }else {
        String newString = s.substring(s.length()-1);
        checksum = Integer.parseInt(newString);

        sum = (7*(Integer.parseInt(""+s.charAt(0))+Integer.parseInt(""+s.charAt(3))+ Integer.parseInt(""+s.charAt(6)))) +
                (3*(Integer.parseInt(""+s.charAt(1))+Integer.parseInt(""+s.charAt(4))+ Integer.parseInt(""+s.charAt(7))))+
             (9*(Integer.parseInt(""+s.charAt(2))+Integer.parseInt(""+s.charAt(5))));


        mod = sum % 10;

        if(mod == checksum)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this code is correct? It's not even calculating all 9 digits. It's only calculating 8 digits. Also, you should be multiplying the first set of digits by 3, the second set of digits by 7, and the third set of digits by 1. See proper algorithm at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_transit_number#Check_digit or http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-the-Check-Digit-of-a-Routing-Number-from-an-Illegible-Check

Answer (score 1):

Please find who needs a routing number validator.

***routing-number.validator.ts***

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';

export const routingNumberValidator = (): ((AbstractControl) => ValidationErrors | null) => {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const targetValue = control.value;

    if (!targetValue) {
        return null;
    }

    const digits = targetValue.split('').map(d => parseInt(d, 10));        
    const checksum = 3 * (digits[0] + digits[3] + digits[6]) + 7 * (digits[1] + digits[4] + digits[7]) + (digits[2] + digits[5] + digits[8]);

    return (checksum % 10 === 0) ? null : { routingnumber: true };
  };
};
```

In your ***yourComponent.component.ts***:

```
this.yourForm = this.fb.group({
   routingNumber: [null, Validators.compose([
      Validators.required,
      routingNumberValidator()
   ])]
});
```

And in your ***yourComponent.component.html***:

```
<nz-form-control [nzErrorTip]="routingNumberErrorTemplate">
    <input
        nz-input
        formControlName="routingNumber"
        id="routingNumber">
</nz-form-control>
<ng-template
    #routingNumberErrorTemplate
    let-control>
    <span data-cy="routing-number-input-error">
        <ng-container *ngIf="control.hasError('required')">The routing number is required</ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="control.hasError('routingnumber')">The routing number is invalid</ng-container>
    </span>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, I wrote a Angular js directive for doing this same thing:

```
angular.module('ldPortal.directives')

.directive('routingnumber', function(){
    return {
      // only use as an attribute
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl){

        var regex = new RegExp('^[0-9]{9}$','');
        var num_at = function(str, index){
          try {
            return parseInt(str.charAt(index))
          }catch (execption){
            console.write(execption);
          }
        };

        var validate = function(value){
          if(! (value)){
            return false;
          }
          var strVal = value.toString();
          if (!regex.test(strVal)){
            return false;
          }
          var checksum = parseInt(strVal.substr(strVal.length-1));
          var sum = 0;
          sum += 7 * (num_at(strVal, 0)+num_at(strVal, 3)+num_at(strVal,6));
          sum += 3 * (num_at(strVal, 1)+num_at(strVal, 4)+num_at(strVal, 7));
          sum += 9 * (num_at(strVal, 2)+num_at(strVal, 5));

          var mod = sum % 10;
          return checksum == mod;
        };


        ctrl.$parsers.push(function(value){
          var is_valid = validate(value);
          ctrl.$setValidity('routingnumber', is_valid);
          return is_valid ? value : undefined;
        });

        ctrl.$formatters.push(function(value){
          var is_valid = validate(value);
          ctrl.$setValidity('routingnumber', is_valid);
          return value;
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: I think this code is incorrect, since it's based on the accepted answer, which I believe is also incorrect.

Comment: can you provide an example of a valid bank routing number that this logic blocks?

Comment: `123123123` is valid, yet not accepted by this code. The code only accounts for 8 of the 9 digits, and the weighting of digits is inaccurate (see Doug S's accurate comment on the accepted answer).

Comment: that is strange. I have had this code in place on our website for over a year, and never run into a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple Routing Validator, hope this works.

RoutingNumberValidator:
    import static java.lang.Character.getNumericValue;

```
public static class RoutingNumberValidator {
    public boolean isValid(String value) {
      boolean isValid = value != null && value.matches("[0-9]{9}");
      if (isValid) {
        int check = 0;
        for ( int index = 0; index < 3; index++ ) {
          int pos = index * 3;
          check += getNumericValue(value.charAt(pos)) * 3;
          check += getNumericValue(value.charAt(pos + 1)) * 7;
          check += getNumericValue(value.charAt(pos + 2));
        }
        isValid = check != 0 && check % 10 == 0;
      }
      return isValid;
    }
}
```

RoutingNumberValidatorTest:

```
public class RoutingNumberValidatorTest {
    private List<String> validRoutingNumbers = Arrays.asList("122105155", "082000549");
    private List<String> invalidRoutingNumbers =  Arrays.asList("1232101155", "032000549");
    @Test
    public void isValid() throws Exception {
        RoutingNumberValidator routingNumberValidator = new RoutingNumberValidator();
        validRoutingNumbers.forEach(it-> assertThat(routingNumberValidator.isValid(it)).as("Invalid Routing Number should not be valid %s", it).isTrue());
        invalidRoutingNumbers.forEach(it-> assertThat(routingNumberValidator.isValid(it)).as("Invalid Routing Number should not be valid %s", it).isFalse());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old and is already answered many times, but this answer from [BrainJar](http://www.brainjar.com/js/validation/) is quite concise and works perfectly. So I thought I'd share.

```
validateRoutingNumber(num: string) {
  // Run through each digit and calculate the total.

  let n = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i += 3) {
    n += parseInt(num.charAt(i), 10) * 3
      + parseInt(num.charAt(i + 1), 10) * 7
      + parseInt(num.charAt(i + 2), 10);
  }

  // If the resulting sum is an even multiple of ten (but not zero),
  // the aba routing number is good.
  if (n != 0 && n % 10 == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

and here is for python:

```
  def validate_routing_number(routing_number):
     # quick easy validations
     if routing_number is None or routing_number == '':
         return False
    invalid_routing_message = 'invalid routing number'
    if not re.match(r'^[0-9]{9}$', routing_number):
        return False

    # here is the more complicated validation!
    checksum = int(routing_number[-1])  # last digit
    sum = 0  # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_transit_number
    sum += 7 * (int(routing_number[0])+int(routing_number[3])+int(routing_number[6]))
    sum += 3 * (int(routing_number[1])+int(routing_number[4])+int(routing_number[7]))
    sum += 9 * (int(routing_number[2])+int(routing_number[5]))

    mod = sum % 10
    return checksum != mod
```

Comment: I think this code is incorrect, since it's based on the accepted answer, which I believe is also incorrect.

Comment: It is also in python when the answer asks for java

Answer (score -2):

```
    package RoutingNumberAlgo;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int checksum = 0, len = 0, sum = 0, mod = 0, rem = 0;
        Scanner ss = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the Routing Number: ");
        String s = ss.nextLine();
        len = s.length();
        if (len != 9) {
            System.out.print("Length not 9");
        } else {
            String newString = s.substring(s.length() - 1);
            checksum = Integer.parseInt(newString);
            sum = (3 * (Integer.parseInt("" + s.charAt(0)))) + (7 * (Integer.parseInt("" + s.charAt(1))))
                    + (1 * (Integer.parseInt("" + s.charAt(2)))) + (3 * (Integer.parseInt("" + s.charAt(3))))
                    + (7 * (Integer.parseInt("" + s.charAt(4)))) + (1 * (Integer.parseInt("" + s.charAt(5))))
                    + (3 * (Integer.parseInt("" + s.charAt(6)))) + (7 * (Integer.parseInt("" + s.charAt(7))));
            mod = 10 - (sum % 10);
            if (mod == checksum)
                System.out.print("True");
            else
                System.out.print("False");
            ;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code should return true or false but you print string into console which is not what he wants. Plus your algorithm seems to have some logical issue. I think you didn't test your code with real bank routing number and also you might just write some explanation with your code to clarify things. your code should be as short as possible meaning no need  to put package/import/main/... ; just the part that does the job would suffice.

Comment: Well the code does work, it needs to be modified a bit but any US routing number will be confirmed valid. I noticed that the sum of the weighted first eight digits needs to be subtracted from the next multiple of ten, hence mod = 10 - (sum % 10)